# Docker SQLServer on MAC

Tags: sql-server, linux, macos, docker

```
docker run --name sqlserver -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=password@123A' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

Error: Dump collecting thread [7] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
```

Docker version: 
Client:
 Version:   17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:03:51 2017
 OS/Arch:   darwin/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: true

OS: Mac

I was running sql-server-linux successfully, but is failing after docker upgrade.

Comment: Have you check out this? https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/136

Comment: yes, not the same issue